# How to set focus on an element of a user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, focus

I have a user control that has a `TextBox` on it. If I set focus on the `TextBox` in the constructor, then the `TextBox` works as expected. Sometimes though, I don't want the `TextBox` to have focus when the user control is first shown, and so I added a property to the user control which sets focus to the `TextBox`. This works, although I get the problem that I can't then reset focus on the `TextBox` after it has lost focus.

Doesn't anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

```
    public ucQueryBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set default values for properties
        CodePrompt = "Barcode";
        TextBoxFontSize = 20;
        TextBoxMaxWidth = 0;
        Label = "";
        LabelFontSize = 20;
        LabelForeground = Colors.White.ToString();
        KeyboardButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

        txtSelection.Focus();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows user to decide whether or the user control should have focus when it loads
    /// Focus puts the green boarder around the textbox
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true)]
    public Boolean SetFocusOnLoad
    {
        get { return _bSetFocusOnLoad; }
        set 
        { 
            _bSetFocusOnLoad = value;

            if (_bSetFocusOnLoad)
                txtSelection.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to be able to answer this for you. The code you think should be returning focus to the textbox probably isn't being executed. Perhaps that line needs to be somewhere else or you need to subscribe to another event that you know will happen when you want to return focus.

Answer (score 1):

Focus in WPF is a complex topic. I think you'll find that the proper way to do what you want is to use `FocusManager` in your XAML:

```
<UserControl ... FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=myTextBox}">
    <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" />
</UserControl>
```

If you use `FocusManager` like this to establish all focus requirements (that is, you use FocusManager on all Windows and UserControls that have any sort of focus requirements), then you'll probably find that all the focusing works exactly like you expect.